# ASP.NET Core Read in html file from www root and replace parameters

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to create a printable page that says

```
Hi, [Member]

We have blah blah....[MemberLocation]

Thanks. Please contact [MemberPhone]
```

Replacing the [Member] tags with data from the model.

I figured the best way is to save an html on wwwroot.
So I saved the above in member.html on wwwroot/staticfiles/member.html

I am having a hard time reading this file into my code.
I was hoping to do something like

```
memberString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("staticfiles/member.html").ToString();
```

Then do something like

```
var memberName = model.Name;
memberString = memberString.replace([Member], memberName)
```

Obviously this isn't working. I can't read the file that way.

I have tried creating a service that reads the file

```
  public class ReturnHTML
 {
    private readonly IHostEnvironment _env;
    public ReturnHTML(IHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public string ReturnHTMLPage()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "StaticFiles/member.html");
        var htmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

        return htmlString.ToString();
    }

}
```

Add this a singleton in my startup.cs

But I can't figure out how to inject this and get this string.

So my question is, what is the best way to create a printable page that I can supply values to?

There are third party stuff out there that create pdf and docs that you can template. But I am not interested in third party tools. Is there any native way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you write the page in Blazor (.razor) itself? Is it required to be kept as a file?

Comment: `ReadAllText("wwwroot/staticfiles/member.html")` will work. And you don't have to `ToString()` everything.

Comment: @HenkHolterman There is no requirement to keep it as a file. Are you suggesting passing the variables to a razor page?

Comment: Yes, that is what Blazor is for. `<p>@member.MemberLocation</p>`. Either with Blazor or Razor.

Comment: Oh for sure @HenkHolterman ...I just wasn't thinking a could use a component to do all this...Heck this will save me lots of time. I am already doing this lol...Thanks